# Rでデータフレームに対し横方向にmaxを取りたい

Tags: r, tidyverse

Rのデータフレームの中にx_1からx_17までカラムがあるのですが、それぞれの行に対してx_1からx_15までの中から最大の値と最大の値を持つカラムを抽出（x6が最大になる場合6を抽出）し、dplyr::mutateして新しい列に追加したいです。
詳しい方、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: dplyr に拘りがなければ `df <- cbind(df, max_idx = apply(df, 1, function(x){which.max(x[1:15])}))`

Answer (score 2):

tidyverseでやるならこんな感じでしょうか。

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris[-5] %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(
    max_idx = which.max(value),
    max_val = max(value)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::pmap`, `base::pmax` でもいけます。

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
set.seed(1)
N_COL <- 17
N_ROW <- 8
df_ <- runif(N_ROW * N_COL) %>%
  round(2) %>%
  matrix(N_ROW, N_COL) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  set_names(str_c("X_", seq_len(MAX_COL))) 

# procedure
df_ %>%
  mutate(X_max = pmap(select(., X_1:X_15), ~ pmax(...)))
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/row-wise-operation-r-using-dplyr/
によると

```
iris %>%
  rowwise() %>% mutate(row_max= max(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width))
```

でいけるようですが、rowwiseは使用があまり推奨されていないとの頁もあるようです。
https://notchained.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/11/15/212117
その際は、回答してくださった方もいるように、purrrで対応するようです。